# Matching an abstract class in Jess Tab Protege

Tags: protege, jess

In my Protege ontology, I have an abstract class `Building` with concrete children classes `Chalet` and `Apartment`.

I want to match them to the LHS of a Jess rule, but I cannot get it to work.

My attempt is as follows:

```
(mapclass Building)
(defrule dummy
    ?vivienda <- (object (is-a Building))
    =>
    (assert (it-worked))
)
```

The rule does not give any parsing error, but it does not match any of my `Building` instances. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only match an instance with the most specific class. If you want to match all instances of a superclass you need to check it explicitly.

As specified in the [JessTab documentation](http://www.ida.liu.se/~hener77/JessTab/JessTab.pdf) there is a boolean function called `superclassp` that checks if a class is the superclass of a second class.
In your example:

```
(mapclass Building)
(defrule dummy
    ?vivienda <- (object (is-a ?subclass))
    (test (superclassp Building ?subclass))
    =>
    (assert (it-worked))
)
```